# Spring Actuator access more datasources

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to add more than one Datasources to healthindicator. But the Spring autoconfiguration throws NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.

My question, is this possible, to make Spring Actuator connect more than one databases?

Thanks!

Comment: It does that by default, but one of the datasources has to be marked `@Primary`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I dont understand what do you mean by "has to be marked". Can you explain that ?

Comment: One of the beans has to the primary bean this is done by putting `@Primary` on one of the beans.

Comment: Hi M.Deinum, thank you very much for explaining that, I think I understand what do you mean. In my case it's a little bit complicated. I'm using Cloud Foundry as plattform, which means, all the datasource beans are automatically injected by the dependecies and the plattform. I cann't actively add @primary to one of the datasource bean.